# Ideals and Kernels of Homomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know in group theory, a normal subgroup is the same with the kernel of a (group) homomorphism. The analogue of normal subgroups in ring theory are ideals.

We know that, the kernel of any (ring) homomorphism is indeed an ideal, and we can construct an (ring) homomorphism given an ideal.

**My question is**, given an ideal $I\subseteq R$, can we construct more than one (ring) homomorphism?

---

I guess we can, but I cannot come up with another (ring) homomorphism besides the canonical projection from $R$ to $R/I$ giving the kernel as $I$. Thanks for help.

Comment: "We can construct a ring homomorphism given an ideal".... presumably you mean "a ring homomorphism give. an ideal **whose kernel is precisely that ideal**" (you need to connect the kernel and the morphism). There are many, but by the isomorphism theorems they all amount to the canonicak projection followed by an inclusion of the quotient into another ring.

Comment: For example, we can map $\mathbb{Z}$ with kernel $2\mathbb{Z}$ into the ring of $2\times 2$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ by sending $a$ to the diagonal matrix with both entries equal to $a+2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin If we denote the canonical projection from $R$ to $R/I$ by $\phi$ and let $f$ be another ring homomorphism from $R$ to some other ring, by the sentence "they all amount to the canonical projection followed by an inclusion of the quotient into another ring", do you mean $f=(f\circ \phi^{-1}) \circ\phi$?

Comment: No, I don't mean that; that makes no sense in general, since $\phi$ is not invertible unless $I=(0)$. I mean that if $f\colon R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism with $\ker f = I$, then there exists a unique injective morphism $\overline{f}\colon R/I\to S$ such that $f = \overline{f}\circ\phi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is that in general there are many such homomorphisms, but from a certain point of view the canonical projection $\pi:R\to R/I$ is essentially the only homomorphism with kernel $I$, in the following sense:

**Canonical decomposition of ring homomorphisms**:
Let $f:R\to S$ be a ring homomorphism, and consider the canonical projection $\pi:R\twoheadrightarrow R/\ker f$ and the inclusion $i:\text{im }f \hookrightarrow S$.
There exists a unique isomorphism $\tilde f:R/\ker f\to \text{im }f$ such that
$$f=i\circ\tilde f\circ\pi $$
i.e. the following diagram commute:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
R @>{f}>> S\\
@V{\pi}VV @AA{i}A\\
R/\ker f @>{\tilde f}>> \text{im }f 
\end{CD}

(You may have called an equivalent result *first isomorphism theorem*, even if this formulation is slightly more general and insightful, in my opinion).

Now, if $f:R\to S$ is any ring homomorphism with $\ker f=I$, then $f$ is equal to the canonical projection $\pi:R\to R/I$ followed by an isomorphism and an inclusion. Hence any different ring isomorphism $\tilde f:R/I\to T$ where $T$ is a subring of any ring $S$ gives rise to a different ring homomorphism $f:R\to S$ with kernel $I$ (by composition with $\pi$ on the right and $i:T\hookrightarrow S$ on the left).
For example, if you consider the ideal $(0)$, all injective ring homomorphisms $f:R\to S$ have kernel $(0)$: therefore in general there are lots of such homomorphisms, even though they are all the same, in the sense specified above.

In fact the question is slightly more sophisticated: all these different homomorphisms are actually the same, up to relabeling elements and extending the codomain, so that often we can just ignore them. However, if we fix the codomain (in such a way that we cannot "cheat" anymore extending it or considering an isomorphic one), the different homomorphisms with kernel $I$ are still equivalent up to isomorphism, but the number of them can be an insightful source of "algebraic information"

For example, there are exactly two homomorphisms
$\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{R}$ with kernel $(x^2-5)$, defined by sending $x$ respectively to $\sqrt{5}$ and $-\sqrt{5}$, but there is only one homomorphism $\mathbb{Q}[x]\to \mathbb{R}$ with kernel $(x^3-2)$ (defined by sending $x$ to $\sqrt[3]2$). These observations are crucial in field theory.

Comment: The last “surjective” should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer. By the last two examples, do you mean that the two homomorphisms from $\mathbb R[x]$ to $\mathbb C$ can be seen as two different extensions of the unique homomorphism from $\mathbb Q[x]$ to $\mathbb R$? It seemed like we not only extended the codomain, but also extended the domain (i.e. from $\mathbb Q[x]$ to $\mathbb R[x]$). This is always the case because of the correspondence theorem, right? Thanks in advance for clarifying my two questions.

Comment: @SamWong In fact the extension of the domain is not relevant, I'm going to edit it in the post. Notice, moreover, that there is a unique homomoprhism $\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{R}$, but there are infinitely many homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}[x]\to\mathbb{R}$. The relevant fact here is strictly related to algebraic properties of the fields $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, and the fact that the latter contains three cube roots of any nonzero element, while in the former there is only one cube root for each element.